# Rails mechanize gem - scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, mechanize

I want to fill in some options which trigger the downloading of a file, using the Mechanize gem.
The HTML is the following.

```
<div>
   <form action="" id="label_selectors" method="post">
     ...
     ...
       <div class="source form_options">                                    
              <select name="source" id="source">                                    
                <option value="btce" selected="selected">Btc-e</option>                                 
                <option value="cryptsy">Cryptsy</option>                                    
             <option value="796">796</option>                                   
                <option value="bitstamp">Bitstamp</option>                                  
                <option value="formulas">Altcoin Indexes</option>                                   
              </select>                                 
            </div>                                  
            <div class="label form_options">                                    
              <select name="label" id="label">                                  
              </select>                                 
            </div>                                  
            <div class="period form_options">                                   
          <select name="period" id="period">                                    
          <option value="15m">15 minute</option>                                    
          <option value="1h" selected="selected">1 hour</option>                                    
          <option value="1d">1 day</option>                                 
          </select>                                 
        </div>                                  
        <div class="presense form_options">                                 
          CSV: <input type="radio" name="presence" value="csv"> Chart: <input type="radio" name="presence" value="chart" checked="checked">                                 
        </div>                                  
        <div class="submit form_options">                                   
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">                                    
        </div>                                  
      </form>                                   
    </div>
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
form = page.forms.first  
form.source = "btce"   
form.label = "BTC/USD"
form.period = "1d"
form.presense = "csv"
form.submit
```

However, it doesn't work:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `presense=' for #<Mechanize::Form:0x007fb878dc7f98
```

(the typo presense rather than presence appears in the page)

How could I fill in this form correctly?

Comment: Add page HTML properly. `<form>` tag is missing

Comment: There is no form tag.

Comment: Strange! I can see `</form>` in page HTML

Comment: Oh, sorry. There was one many lines above: `<form action="" id="label_selectors" method="post">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `presence` input is a radio button.

To select a radio button with mechanize you'll want something like:

```
form.radiobuttons_with(name: 'presence')[0].check
```

There's other ways to select radio buttons with mechanize - you can see them here: http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html